# Class 'kartik\sidenav\SideNav' not found

Tags: github, widget, yii2

My backend/layout/view/main.php file is as following
Please tell me how to use kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav
I've installed this widget by composer. I'm new to Yii. Please help.
I'm not sure whether I'm using the code in the right place or why this error is coming.I've copied and pasted the code from the github page.

```
<?php

/* @var $this \yii\web\View */
/* @var $content string */

use backend\assets\AppAsset;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\Nav;
use yii\bootstrap\NavBar;
use yii\widgets\Breadcrumbs;
use common\widgets\Alert;
//use kartik\widgets\SideNav;
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
//use yii\helpers\Url;


AppAsset::register($this);
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?= Yii::$app->language ?>">
<head>
<meta charset="<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<?= Html::csrfMetaTags() ?>
<title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
<?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php $this->beginBody() ?>
<?= SideNav::widget([
'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
'heading' => 'Options',
'items' => [
    [
        'url' => '#',
        'label' => 'Home',
        'icon' => 'home'
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Help',
        'icon' => 'question-sign',
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'About', 'icon'=>'info-sign', 'url'=>'#'],
            ['label' => 'Contact', 'icon'=>'phone', 'url'=>'#'],
        ],
    ],
    ],
]);

?>       

<div class="wrap">
<?php
NavBar::begin([
    'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
    'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
    'options' => [
        'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
    ],
]);
$menuItems = [
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
];
if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
} else {
    $menuItems[] = [
        'label' => 'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username .     ')',
        'url' => ['/site/logout'],
        'linkOptions' => ['data-method' => 'post']
    ];
 }
 echo Nav::widget([
    'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
    'items' => $menuItems,
 ]);
 NavBar::end();
 ?>

 <div class="container">
    <?= Breadcrumbs::widget([
        'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ?         $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
    ]) ?>
    <?= Alert::widget() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
</div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
    <p class="pull-left">&copy; My Company <?= date('Y') ?></p>

    <p class="pull-right"><?= Yii::powered() ?></p>
</div>
</footer>

<?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Comment: find out how to install kartik widgets here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384920/include-additional-library-to-yii2/35388744#35388744](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384920/include-additional-library-to-yii2/35388744#35388744)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it odd that you have the vendor directory within (inside)  the backend. Because I think you're using advanced templates the vendor directory should be only inside of your project, and then at the same level of frontend and backend (and not inside them). I think this is the reason for which Yii can not find the component SideNav ..

I suggest you of reinstall this extension byb running  (its) composer in your project,  in this way the extension should end up  in the vendor directory of the project ..
Once you have installed this if you install only SideNav then it should work ..

```
use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;
```

but if you install all the widgets should work

```
use kartik\widgets\SideNav;
```

Comment: I've tried that. Then the error message turns to - "Class 'kartik\widgets\SideNav' not found".

Comment: Stuck at the same place.

Comment: Have you installed all the widgets or only SideNav .. ?

Comment: I've installed SideNav only.

Comment: I have installed all the widget and work fine with the suggestion in answer.. .. show me the path of  the SideNav code in vendor  ..

Comment: In backend\vendor\kartik-v\yii2-widget-sidenav\asset\s\sidenav.php I have namespace kartik\sidenav;

Comment: Strange in backend i have the vendor dir in project .. then i have only one vendor dir both backend and frontend .. how /where you have executed .. composer  for installation .. of this extension.. ?

Comment: I need to edit backend\views\layouts\main.php. Right?

Comment: Yes .. you shoudl change the use backend\vendor\kartik\widgets\SideNav; in you layout

Comment: When I'm using only "use kartik\sidenav\SideNav;" the code at least returns me the index.php page. But as soon as I type "<?php echo SideNav::widget([ ]) ?>" in the body - It's throwing the error.

Comment: use is only a declaration to allow the code to find the external components needed (it's kind of statement for a possible includes) so long as it is not actually used a check is not made. so this is normal .. A question still you're using basic or advanced template?

Comment: well, this problem was not easy to solve ... In any case when you add the extension with composer remember to always run it from the project directory